# What is a state-dependent class in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

What is a state-dependent class in Java? I am reading JCIP and can not figure out what state-dependent class means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

> The class libraries include a number of state‐dependent classes ‐ those having operations with state‐based preconditions ‐ such as  FutureTask ,  Semaphore , and  BlockingQueue . For example, you cannot remove an item from an empty queue or retrieve the result of a task that has not yet finished; before these operations can proceed, you must wait until the queue enters the "nonempty" state or the task enters the "completed" state.

JCIP, page 179.